# Beautiful soup Scrape Movie Titles and Images

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to follow the course and I'm stuck in one example because the website content and tags got changed.
In a course the tag looks:

now it's  but even when I change the class I can't return anything.
I'd like to scrape the movie Titles and Images. html image picture is here.

[image]

```
response = requests.get('https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2')
best_movies = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(best_movies, 'html.parser')

titles = soup.find_all(name = 'h3', class_ = 'jsx-2692754980')
print(titles)

imgs = soup.find_all(name='img', class_='jsx-4015086601')
print(imgs)
imgs_li=[]
for e in imgs:
    link = e.get('src')
    imgs_li.append(link)
print(imgs_li)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to explore `selenium` along with `BeautifulSoup`.

Here's how:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser").find_all("img")

movies = []
for image in soup:
    try:
        if image["alt"]:
            movies.append([image["alt"], f"https:{image['data-src']}"])
    except KeyError:
        continue

for movie in movies[1:]:
    title, link = movie
    print(f"{title}\n{link}\n{'-' * 80}")
```

Output:

```
Stand By Me
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5e62/24d4/08ba/aa5a/8143/279c/stand-by-me.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Raging Bull
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5d2d/d990/853e/7cd6/60cc/fa2e/raging-bull.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Amelie
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/empire-images/features/59395a49f68e659c7aa3a1a8/Amelie.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Leonardo DiCaprio and Kate Winslet in Titanic
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/lifestyle-images/celebrity/59d4ac2c07c78ace382c4735/kate-winslet-leonardo-dicaprio-titanic.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Good Will Hunting
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5e62/2a32/2cd5/547b/bf0f/6416/good-will-hunting.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Arrival
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5e62/2ac7/2eea/4450/3534/4b45/Arrival.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lost In Translation
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5e62/2b5f/232f/f064/694b/c738/lost-in-translation.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Princess Bride
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5e62/2bf3/08ba/aa7b/8f43/27e0/the-princess-bride.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Terminator
https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/empire-images/features/59395a49f68e659c7aa3a1a8/The%2520Terminator.jpg?format=jpg&quality=80&width=500&ratio=1-1&resize=aspectfit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

and so on ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This website is dynamic, so using `bs4` will not work here (see [page source](http://view-source:https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2)). I would recommend you using `selenium` to grab page source and pass it in soup object. Here is the sample code to do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2'
chrome_driver_path = 'chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Retrieve url in headless browser
    driver.get(url)

    html = driver.page_source

    driver.close()


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

titles = soup.find_all(name='h3', class_='jsx-2692754980')
titles = [i.text for i in titles if i.text is not None]
print(titles)

imgs = soup.find('div', class_='jsx-3821216435').find_all('img')
print(imgs)
```

The results for titles and imgs are:

```
titles -- ['100) Stand By Me', '99) Raging Bull', '98) Amelie', '97) Titanic', '96) Good Will Hunting', '95) Arrival', '94) Lost In Translation' ... ]

imgs --- [<img alt="Stand By Me" class="jsx-952983560 loading" data-src="//cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5e62/24d4/08ba/aa5a/8143/279c/stand-by-me.jpg?format=jpg&amp;quality=80&amp;width=500&amp;ratio=1-1&amp;resize=aspectfit" src="" title=""/>, <img alt="Raging Bull" class="jsx-952983560 loading" data-src="//cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5d2d/d990/853e/7cd6/60cc/fa2e/raging-bull.jpg?format=jpg&amp;quality=80&amp;width=500&amp;ratio=1-1&amp;resize=aspectfit" src="" title=""/>, ... ]
```

**Note that** you need to `pip install selenium` then download `chromedriver` and put it in the same directory with script.

Answer (score 0):

Given Selenium might be a little advanced, you may try using what you already know, how about using string tokenisation?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/"
movies_page = requests.get(url)
page = movies_page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

long_string = str(soup).split('"title":"100 Greatest Movies 2021"')[1]
parts = long_string.split('","altText":"')[:101]
with open('top_100_movies.txt', 'a') as file:
    for part in parts[::-1]:
        file.write(part.split(',"titleText":"')[1])
        file.write('\n')
```

[image: You can still achieve the required result]